# Find $f,$ given that $\sum_{i=1}^n f (p_i (x_1,...,x_k))=0 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functional-equations

Reading through some math Olympiads it appears that there is a whole class of problems of this form:

Let $p_1,\ldots,p_n\in\mathbb {R}[x_1,\ldots,x_k] $ with $k,n\in \mathbb {N}^*$

Find all $f:\mathbb {R}\rightarrow\mathbb {R} $ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n f (p_i (x_1,\ldots,x_k))=0 $

Is there a general method, or approach for these problems? What happens when $f:\mathbb {N}\rightarrow \mathbb {N} $?

A trivial result is that $f (0)=0$ and heuristically is worth trying some values to evaluate the polynomials, looking at the roots of the polynomials or at the roots of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{p_i(x_1,...,x_k)}$.

Can we expand on that?

Edit:since the above seems far too broad a case, we can ask the same questions in the case  $\sum_{i=1}^n f (a_{i_1}x_1+...+a_{i_k}x_k)=0 $, with $a_{i_j}\in\mathbb {R} $

Comment: Solving functional equations is an art. Experience is the key, allowing you to build a sufficiently large repertoire of possible moves.

Comment: This won't work in general, consider for example $\,k=n=2\,$ with $\,p_1(x_1,x_2)=x_1$, $\,p_2(x_1,x_2)=x_2\,$. You'll need (a lot) more constraints to make it feasible.

Comment: (Answering to quasi)I agree with that. I also think that there has to be some work made by good mathematicians on the topic and I would really enjoy a more abstract view on the problem. And by "more abstract" I don't mean only in a highly formalized way, but also in a purely heuristic way (which, I guess, is closer to the "repertoire of possible moves" you are referring to)

Comment: (Answering to dxiv) are you suggesting to study a more manageable case like, for example, if no variable has an exponent greater than 1?

Comment: @LucioTanzini `(Answering to dxiv)` Use `@dxiv` instead if you mean the other poster to be notified that you ping'd them. `are you suggesting to study a more manageable case` Some more context, and examples of what you are *actually* looking for could help frame it better.

Comment: Thanks @dxiv, I hope the edit makes it clearer